# InputTextarea in Dialog shouldn't process but it does

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have an inputTextArea in a dialog and wanted that the bean property shouldn't be sent/changed when the user clicks on the cancel button, but it does.

```
<p:dialog header="Notizen" id="paketNotizenDialog" modal="true"
            widgetVar="paketNotizenDialogWV">
            <h:form>
                <p:panelGrid columns="1">
                    <p:inputTextarea  scrollHeight="200" rows="6" cols="33" autoResize="false"
                        value="#{paketErstellenDialogController.selectedPaket.notiz}" />
                </p:panelGrid>
                <p:commandButton value="Save" process="@form" oncomplete="PF('paketNotizenDialogWV').hide();"/>

                <p:commandButton value="Cancel" oncomplete="PF('paketNotizenDialogWV').hide();" process="@none" update="@none" />
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
```

The button which opens the dialog:

```
<p:commandButton id="notizEintragButton" value="T" process="@this"
                        onclick="PF('paketNotizenDialogWV').show();" />
```

Any hints? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using the `commandButton`, the default behaviour would be to submit the enclosing form with ajax request.

I suspect what you want to do here is to reset the form input and close the dialog. In that case you should go for the `type="reset"` which according to the primefaces doc:

> Reset buttons do not submit the form, just resets the form contents.

And once that is done, trigger your closing javascript code:

```
<p:commandButton value="Cancel" type="reset" 
      onclick="PF('paketNotizenDialogWV').hide();"/>
```

If you do not want to reset the form, just close the dialog then use:

```
<p:commandButton value="Cancel" type="button" 
    onclick="PF('paketNotizenDialogWV').hide();"/>
```

Which according to the primefaces doc would:

> Push buttons are used to execute custom javascript without causing an
>   ajax/non-ajax request. To create a push button set type as "button"

**Update**

If you want to reset the values from the backing bean then use [reset input fields](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/resetInput.xhtml) functionality of primefaces.

In your case it would be something like:

```
<p:panelGrid columns="1">
       <p:inputTextarea  id="input" scrollHeight="200" rows="6" cols="33" autoResize="false"
              value="#{paketErstellenDialogController.selectedPaket.notiz}" />
</p:panelGrid>

<p:commandButton value="Cancel" oncomplete="PF('paketNotizenDialogWV').hide();" 
     process="@this" update="input" >
    <p:resetInput target="input" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Comment: I just don't want that the bean property is being set in case the user is clicking the cancel button. A new reopening should show the last bean property state...

Comment: Then the second option would work for you. type="button"

Comment: It didn't work. I just wanted that the value when opening the dialog should remain when I click on cancel. But when I type in the new value and click on cancel and reopen the dialog the value was overriden.

Comment: Ok i see, so when the page is loaded.. that inputTextArea is already loaded with some data.. so this is like the update page of some sort right? And on cancel you want to populate the inputare with that initial data?

Comment: yeah exactly. The dialog has a parent dialog which loads in the last value from the bean property.

Comment: Is paketErstellenDialogController a ViewScoped bean?

Comment: Yes it is a ViewScoped bean.

Comment: I just want that the bean property should remain if I press cancel. E.g. value in bean property is 123. When I open the dialog and type in 123000 and click on cancel the value should stay 123 and not 123000 when I reopen the dialog.

Comment: This perfectly worked for me now. I misunderstood your solution the first time now it's clear. You wipe out the textArea and tell to get the bean value again. Thank you very much.

Comment: Great. Glad i could help

Comment: Just Curious. Is there anything similiar for selectOneMenus?

Answer (score 0):

just add `type="button"` and remove `process="@none" update="@none"` 
from `<p:commandButton value="Cancel" oncomplete="PF('paketNotizenDialogWV').hide();" process="@none" update="@none" />`

Comment: It didn't work. I just wanted that the value when opening the dialog should remain when I click on cancel. But when I type in the new value and click on cancel and reopen the dialog the value was overriden.

Comment: did you try to put form tag outside <p:dialog> tag?